# pulling out data matches for a list(of T) with condition

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, match

Given a descending sorted list: List(Of Date)

```
allDates.Sort(Function(d1, d2) d2.CompareTo(d1))
```

I am trying to figure out what is the most efficient and quickest method to extract the sets of dates that match where the count of matching dates is greater than some supplied parameter. 
I could do this in a for each loop but thought LINQ might be quicker/more efficient.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Here is what Im currently doing which works fine, just looking for a more efficient way if there is one

```
allDates.GroupBy(Function(n) n).Select(Function(g) New With {.Number = g.Key, .Quantity = g.Count}).OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Quantity).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: LINQ is for clarity and succinctness.  It does not make your code any faster to use LINQ, because underneath it still has to do a for loop somewhere.  Unless you're talking about millions of elements, please don't optimize prematurely - use code that is easy to understand and simple to maintain.

Comment: Good advice, which I agree with, see updated post